# How to set a TextArea read-only (but scrollable)?

Tags: vaadin

How does one set a TextArea as read-only?

I have a longer text-field that I want to display but which should be read-only for certain user-roles, i.e. not modifiable. It should however remain scrollable (because its contents can be much longer than what is visible). It should behave like a "normal" TextArea, but only some users should be able to actually modify its content.

TextArea has a method `setReadOnly(boolean)` which I first thought to provide exactly that functionality, but it seems to be a no-op, at least I don't see any effect from setting it. The method `setEnabled(boolean)` on the other hand makes the text-area readonly, but also non-scrollable, which makes it unusable for my purpose.

Any suggestion? This is using Vaadin v20.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Blush!) I have to back-paddle! The setReadOnly()-method DOES work as expected! My boolean expression that I had used to toggle it turned out to be always false. The problem was in front of the glass - not behind!
Apologies for the bandwidth wasted!

Answer (score 1):

TextArea should support the readonly state just like a single line TextField, and the web component `<vaadin-text-area readonly>` works as expected. Please report a bug at https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/new/choose